# Timer object run under Background Service issue

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, backgroundworker

I have a project about Background Worker problem.
For my backgroundservice
I have:

```
public ServiceWorker(IServiceProvider provider, IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
{
    this.serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    this.provider = provider;
}

protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        using (var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            if (timerObject ==null)
            {
                var workerService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IWorkerService>();
                timerObject = new TimerObject(workerService);
                timerObject.StartTimer();
            }
            await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, the timerobject process job overtime, and will throw exception as below

> Exception Found: System.InvalidOperationException: Exception in SessionExtendHandle(), Detail : System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection

if put `var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope()` outside, it will cause memory leak. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: By "overtime" you mean "timeout"? Where is timerobject declared? What does it look like? And one more: Have you tried _not_ to use `using` ?

Comment: There have some method which retreive the data from outside long and get delay for it

Comment: Well, as it _seems_ to me, your timer holds on to a reference to an IWorkerService for too long because by the time the timer is trying to use it, it has been disposed already. And that seems to be because its scope has been disposed.

Comment: My guess would be that the workerService is registered as scoped, so is disposed after one second, and the timer tries to use the service after that point. But from the current example there is really no way to know since it does not show the registration, the timerObject or anything else relevant. Also, `Task.Delay` is a bit suspicious, it may have been added to hide a bug instead of fixing it.

Comment: Please post a minimal, reproducible example.